# How to get the text from the textbox added to the ListBox?

Tags: vb6

So i made a notepad type of software from Visual Baisc 6 and i am trying to add the text from my textbox to the Listbox. I tried to do many things but couldn't. I am not able to get to the correct code to do that.

Comment: AddItem? Show us your code and we can help.

Comment: We haven't seen anything you've tried or error messages generated from what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I used list box `"lstListBox"` a text box `"txtText"` and a command button `"cmdAdd"`

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    lstListBox.AddItem txtText.Text
End Sub
```

this worked for me should work for you too, just like what OldBoyCoder commented hope this helps you understand better what he meant.

Comment: Wow. Good Job. Thx

Comment: @Shivam Dokania You should mark my answer as complete since it's the right thing to do, even though I don't really need the reputation.